# Cannot execute context.route in for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I'm using route.abort() to block some URLs.

When I'm using code like this:

```
await this.context.route(/a.net/, route => route.abort());
```

works as expected.

BUT since I have a lot of routes to block instead of writing multiple lines of code above I wanted to create config with routes to block and execute await in for loop.

My config.ts like:

```
export const config = {
    use: {
        some_list: '/a.net/,/b.net/,/c.net/'
    },
};
```

rest of the code to block all routes from list:

```
let listOfResources = config.use.some_list.split(',')
for (let value of listOfResources) {
        await this.context.route(value, route => route.abort());
}
```

but in the above For loop the aborting or routes is not happening, could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
let endpoints = ['/a.net', '/b.net', '/c.net']

 endpoints.forEach((path) => {
      this.context.route(path, route => route.abort());
    });
```

I'm not very familiar with route.abort() function but maybe this could help.